# Number validation in angular 2

Tags: validation, angular

Angular 2 (2.0.0) + TS.

I have to set validation rules with `<input>` tag in column of table.

For expample, I have some table and input:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>Values: {{ dataFromServer }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input type="number" placeholder="maxvalue">
<input type="number" placeholder="minvalue">
```

`dataFromServer` is a value, which I get from server, and is equal `255`.

I add `maxvalue = 100` and `minvalue = 20`, and then `Values: 255` got red. How to implement this? Or give please me some interesting examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you html code like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td ng-class="{'colorRed': dataFromServer > maxvalue || dataFromServer < minvalue }">Values: {{ dataFromServer }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input type="number" placeholder="maxvalue" ng-model="maxvalue">
<input type="number" placeholder="minvalue" ng-model="minvalue">
```

And add css like

```
.colorRed {
    color:red;
}
```